# C# thread static fields from generic abstract class

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic abstract class with thread static fields, defined as such:

```
abstract MyClass<T>
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static bool A;
}
```

Once I derive from this class:

```
MyOtherClass : MyClass<string>
```

What happens to the field A?

- Does *MyOtherClass* have its own thread static fields?
- or, is there a set of shared thread static fields for all classes derived from *MyClass*?

And, if the fields are per derived class, if I do this:

```
MyOtherClass1 : MyClass<string>
MyOtherClass2 : MyClass<bool>
MyOtherClass3 : MyClass<string>
```

As *MyOtherClass1* and *MyOtherClass3* have the same types, would the fields be shared?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Derived classes do not have a separate copy of static variables.  Usages of a generic class with different generic type arguments however *do* each have their own copy of `static` variables.  So `MyOtherClass1` and `MyOtherClass3` will share the same variables, as they have the same generic type arguments for `MyClass`, and `MyOtherClass2` will have a different set of variables because it doesn't share the same generic arguments.